# PHP "Use of undefined constant length" Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Can someone tell me why the constant length isn't defined? I'm using `glob` to find and put all .txt files into an array then using `for` to loop through them echoing them out.

```
$filew = glob("/xampp/htdocs/new/*.txt"); 
for($n=0; $n<$filew.length; $n++) { 
  $filew['$n'] = substr($filew['$n'], 18, -4);
  echo $filew['n'] . " ";
}
```

The error message indicates the problem lines in the second line, someone told me to put array content into quote marks but it hasn't worked. Thank you

Comment: `$filew.length` should be `count($filew)`

Comment: php doesn't have an `array.length` parameter, that is javascript. use `count($filew)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP arrays don't have a length property.  You should use `count` instead

```
$filew = glob("/xampp/htdocs/new/*.txt"); 
for($n = 0; $n < count($filew); $n++) { 
  $filew[$n] = substr($filew[$n], 18, -4);
  echo $filew[$n] . " ";
}
```

You also have some errors in the way you are accessing your array.  Using a single quote will cause the variable inside to not be rendered.  Using `$filew['$n']` will not give you a numeric value for `$n`.  It will give a literal string with the value `$n`. Remove the single quotes should be just fine.

Comment: Great to hear. Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it answered your question.